# Google no actualiza los metadatos

Tags: wordpress

Verán, tengo una página web la cual cuando la busco en Google, muestra la última Entrada que se ha escrito en la parte de la metadescripción.
Para cambiar eso, me he ido a los metadatos de la página y he puesto una frase:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me voy al buscador Yahoo, y ha funcionado:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero en Google sigue como estaba antes:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Como se hace para que Google se anime a actualizar los nuevos metadatos?
De hecho, la entrada que muestra no es la última, sino la penúltima, indicando que esta muy retrasado.

Edito: He visto que hay algún misterioso error, como se puede comprobar en https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool#url=autismocadiz.org:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si entendí bien, el fallo esta en el siguiente widget:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Parece que falta algunos datos.
Segun esto, en el widget tipo Información de contacto y mapas, me falta una imagen y nombre, pero no encuentro donde deberían estar estas variables dentro de ese tipo de widget.

Comment: ¿Hace cuánto hiciste esos cambios en los `meta`? Google tarda alrededor de un par de días en aplicarlos.

Comment: Los metadatos ya están actualizados, sólo que tardan en aparecer en los resultados de búsqueda, como bien dice @phpMyGuel. [Puedes verificarlo con la herramienta de Google](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool#url=autismocadiz.org). Mira a tu derecha, tienes errores y advertencias que deberías corregir, quizá eso retrase la aparición de los nuevos metadatos.

Comment: Cierto, he visto que hay algún que otro fallo. Tendre que ver como corregirlos.

Comment: He actualizado.

Comment: He creado otra entrada para el tema del error que advierte la herramienta de google.